# The composition of the logit function and its inverse is not numerically invariant to decimal places

Tags: functions

I've defined the two following functions:

```
logit[x_] := Module[{},
   Log[x/(1 - x)]
   ];
invLogit[x_] := Module[{},
   E^x/(1 + E^x)
   ];
```

One is the inverse of the other. However,

```
In[37]:= logit[invLogit[34.55555]]

Out[37]= 34.6574
```

Is there a way to increase the precision of the calculations?

Comment: ``logit[invLogit[34.55555`20]]``.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thanks for the comment. However, if these functions have to receive a variable, how would I do then? e.g. logit[invLogit[s]], where s is some value computed in another function.

Comment: The inverse relationship is only valid for real values of `x`. Evaluate `logit[invLogit[2 + 8 I]] // Simplify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works

```
logit[x_] := Module[{}, Log[x/(1 - x)]];
invLogit[u_] := Module[{x}, x = SetPrecision[u, 30]; E^x/(1 + E^x)];

logit[invLogit[34.55555]]
(* 34.5555500000000 *)
```

The issue is that the gradient of `logit` approaches zero for large arguments.  Therefore there is a loss of precision in evaluating it.  Enforcing a larger precision calculation helps get back to where you started.

Comment: Mikado, thanks for your answer. In the set precision command, is the $MaxExtraPrecision the best numerical approximation we can have in general terms in mathematica?

Comment: From the help for `$MaxExtraPrecision` I don't think that it is relevant here.  I think you can specify as many extra digits of precision as you need.