# logit ScalingFunctions

Tags: plotting, numerics, bugs, warning-messages, logarithmic-scale

Having learned how to make symlog axes in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216276/7936), I was interested in the [logit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/scales.html) scale, the transforms of which are

```
logit = {
    Function[x, Log[x/(1 - x)]],
    Function[y, Exp[y]/(1 + Exp[y])]
    };
```

These functions are inverses of one another, as required.  Then, trying

```
Plot[x, {x, 10^-3, 1 - 10^-3}, ScalingFunctions -> logit, Frame -> True]
```

I get a figure

[image: x with problematic logit axis]

There are two problems.  First, I get a message in the Messages window,

```
 Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
```

which causes the red frame.  Second, only the first set of ticks above 0.5 are there (up to 0.9, further decades are missing)

Weirdly, when I evaluate lots of other expressions immediately after plotting---`0`, for example---the red frame goes away.

I think the issue may be [an imprecise evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187152/7936) but using `SetPrecision` as suggested in that question does not seem to fix the issue.

Questions:

- Where are the top half of the ticks?  How do I get them to show up?
- How do I prevent the red frame and divide-by-0 error?

Comment: a work-around: ``ticks = Quiet@
   Append[{logit[[1]]@.9, "0.900", {0.03, 0.}, 
      AbsoluteThickness[.1]}]@
    Charting`ScaledTicks[logit, "TicksLength" -> {.03, .02}][
     logit[[1]][10^-3], logit[[1]][1 - 10^-3]];
Plot[logit[[1]]@x, {x, 10^-3, 1 - 10^-3}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]``

Comment: The failing of the ticks is confirmed as a bug by Wolfram support.

Comment: The error message + red frame was fixed in 13.0 but the missing ticks were not.