# How to plot with x axis as given by logit function

Tags: plotting

```
 x1 = {0.009`, 0.019`, 0.029`, 0.039`, 0.049`, 0.059`, 0.069`, 0.079`, 
   0.089`, 0.099`, 0.109`, 0.119`, 0.129`, 0.139`, 0.149`, 0.159`, 
   0.169`, 0.179`, 0.189`, 0.199`, 0.209`, 0.219`, 0.229`, 0.239`, 
   0.249`, 0.259`, 0.269`, 0.279`, 0.289`, 0.299`, 0.309`, 0.319`, 
    0.329`, 0.339`, 0.349`, 0.359`, 0.369`, 0.379`, 0.389`, 0.399`, 
   0.409`, 0.419`, 0.429`, 0.439`, 0.449`, 0.459`, 0.469`, 0.479`, 
   0.489`, 0.499`, 0.509`, 0.519`, 0.529`, 0.539`, 0.549`, 0.559`, 
   0.569`, 0.579`, 0.589`, 0.599`, 0.609`, 0.619`, 0.629`, 0.639`, 
   0.649`, 0.659`, 0.669`, 0.679`, 0.689`, 0.699`, 0.709`, 0.719`, 
   0.729`, 0.739`, 0.749`, 0.759`, 0.769`, 0.779`, 0.789`, 0.799`, 
   0.809`, 0.819`, 0.829`, 0.839`, 0.849`, 0.859`, 0.869`, 0.879`, 
   0.889`, 0.899`, 0.909`, 0.919`, 0.929`, 0.939`, 0.949`, 0.959`, 
   0.969`, 0.979`, 0.989`, 0.999`};
  x2 = {142.741111`, 56.431111`, 35.803333`, 25.991111`, 20.416667`, 
   17.277778`, 14.936667`, 12.807778`, 11.506667`, 10.402222`, 
   9.631111`, 8.583333`, 7.686666`, 7.137778`, 6.663334`, 6.295556`, 
   5.911111`, 5.653333`, 5.313333`, 5.192222`, 4.876667`, 4.574444`, 
   4.138889`, 4.201111`, 3.798889`, 3.608889`, 3.765555`, 3.22`, 
   3.145556`, 3.128889`, 2.928889`, 2.88`, 2.87`, 2.542222`, 
   2.508889`, 2.563333`, 2.372222`, 2.481111`, 2.324444`, 2.328889`, 
   2.131111`, 2.086667`, 2.108889`, 2.168889`, 2.061111`, 1.858889`, 
   2.098889`, 1.936667`, 1.924444`, 1.806667`, 1.754445`, 1.865556`, 
   1.773333`, 1.824445`, 1.682222`, 1.666667`, 1.546667`, 1.581111`, 
   1.614444`, 1.452222`, 1.554444`, 1.436667`, 1.514444`, 1.41`, 
    1.493333`, 1.386667`, 1.377778`, 1.324445`, 1.388889`, 1.291111`, 
    1.345556`, 1.276667`, 1.168889`, 1.194444`, 1.082222`, 1.212222`, 
   1.097778`, 1.163334`, 1.176667`, 1.186667`, 1.2`, 1.08`, 1.073333`,
    1.115556`, 1.035556`, 1.038889`, 1.08`, 1.077778`, 1.024444`, 
    1.034444`, 0.985556`, 1.015556`, 0.97`, 1.097778`, 1.018889`, 
    1.014444`, 0.948889`, 1.02`, 0.946667`, 1.278889`};
   Data1 = Transpose@{x1, x2};

 sd = 0.24/2;
 N1 = 1000;
 mu = 0.001;
  ud = 0.08;
  theta = 2 N1 mu;
 a1 = ListLogLinearPlot[{Data1}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "SFS"}, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], PlotStyle -> {Blue}]
   c = LogLinearPlot[{theta/x Exp[-ud /sd ], theta/x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", "H(t)"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[.003], FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
    PlotStyle -> { {Blue, Dashed}, Blue}];

     Show[a1, c]
```

Similar to log log plot, here i need log logit plot. the x axis should be given by logit function. the reason why i want this is to enhance the late x axis regime.

Comment: Have you already seen the `ScalingFunctions` option of `ListPlot[]` and related functions?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [your previous one on the same topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/269672/27951)? What is not satisfactory about the potential solution in [logit ScalingFunctions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253205/27951) that I mentioned to you last time?

Comment: Yes, I checked. But i could not understand how to make x axis as logit function. I want to enhance the x axis range in the interval 0.5 to 1 using logit scale on the axis. Could you please tell me the commands?

Comment: Have you understood the question? The x axis should look like logit scale which means more spaced region at the higher x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `Data1`, we can generate a logit plot manually as shown below. Here we generate the ticks manually to obtain "nice" spacings and results (and also because, [as was reported previously in a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253205/27951), the ticks don't play well with `ScalingFunctions` in this case.

```
xticks = 
  {Log[1/(1 - #)], #, {0, 0.02}} & /@ 
    {0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.9, 0.98, 0.99, 0.995, 0.998, 0.999};

ListPlot[
  {Log[1/(1 - #1)], #2} & @@@ Data1,
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {xticks, None}}
]
```

[image: manually-generated logit-linear plot]

Comment: @MacroB Thank you so much!!